# Scaling X values on step chart

Tags: google-sheets

Using Google Sheets and the following data

```
X Y
4 10
2 12
1 14
```

The available step area chart uses one unit for all X values. Like this:

[image]

Is it possible to scale the X gap based on the values? Some thing like this:

```
            -
       -----
-------
4 4 4 4 2 2 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your source table above in A1:B4 of a sheet, you can try:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(tocol(reduce(,A2:A4,lambda(acc,arr,{acc;sequence(arr,1,arr,0)})),1),A2:B4,{1,2},FALSE))
```

The REDUCE creates an array of N of each value in the X column then this array is used in a VLOOKUP on the source table, returning the required replicates of both the X&Y columns. Use the output of this formula as the source for your stepped area chart.